# How to hide the axis lines that show when moving objects?

Tags: animation

when you move an object in blender, say in x, a red line shows up to show that you are moving it in x. its really annoying. is there a way to hide the lines that show up when moving stuff in blender? thank you

Comment: The only way I know about is to set the viewport shading to Render

Comment: i seem to lose all my ctrls when setting viewport shading to render. as well as using only render under display options. 

The lines im talking about are only visibile when you drag/move objects or ctrls around in the 3d viewport. if youre moving multiple things around it really clutters the view and hard to see

Comment: can you upload the .blend file? Also are you using Blender 2.9X or 2.8 ? When I try to replicate the same, I get only one line, unless I'm using for Pivot Point individual origins, and using local for Transform Orientation

Comment: i cant upload the file. but its pretty simple what im talking about. literally open blender and move the cube around using the manipulator. the lines that show up when moving the cube. thats what i want to hide, im using 2.78